# Reportlab bar chart bar label callouts

Tags: python, bar-chart, reportlab

I would like to be able to label the bars themselves on the bar chart in a callout like below.  I've looked around for a reportlab example of how to do this and can not find anything.[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

```
bc.barLabels.fontName = "Helvetica"
bc.barLabels.fontSize = 8
bc.barLabels.fillColor = black
bc.barLabelFormat = '%d'
bc.barLabels.nudge = 7
```